# Debugging JavaScript & css code: adding an event handler

Tags: javascript

You can see the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/KfwyL/
I have a div and inside of the div there is an h1. I have the h1 set so that on hover it becomes green. I want to make it so that when the mouse hovers over the h1, the div gets a box shadow. my code is not working.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../stylesheets/1.css"> 
<title> Max Pleaner's First Website
</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="welcomebox"> 
    <h1 class="welcometext">Welcome to my site.
    </h1> 
    </div>
</body>
<<script src="../Scripts/1.js"> </script>
</html>
```

css:

```
body {
    background-image:url('../images/sharks.jpg');
    }

.welcomebox {background-color:#1C0245;
  -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
  -moz-border-radius: 18px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  width: 390px;
  height: 78px;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top:28px;
    border-style:solid;
  border-width:medium;
}

h1 {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 12px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 357px;
    background-color: #670715;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
  -moz-border-radius: 14px;
  border-radius: 14px;
}

h1:hover {background-color: green;}
```

Javascript:

```
welcomeboxshadow = document.getElementsByClass("welcometext");

function doit()
{
var topbox = document.getElementsbyClass("welcomebox")
topbox.style.box-shadow = "-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(114, 220, 215, 1);-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(114, 220, 215, 1);box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px rgba(114, 220, 215, 1);"
};
welcomeboxshadow.onmouseover.doit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/KfwyL/22/) is a working version of your code that doesn't use jQuery since I figured you wanted to know how to do this in pure JS...

```
welcomeboxshadow = document.getElementsByClassName("welcometext");
welcomeboxshadow[0].addEventListener('mouseover', 
                                  function() {
                                      var topbox = document.getElementsByClassName("welcomebox");
 topbox[0].setAttribute("class","welcomebox welcomeBoxMouseOver")
                                  }, false)
```

I changed the inline style to a class but the concept is the same.

The problems were mostly invalid function names (getElementsByClass**Name**), trying to set properties that didn't exist (`topbox.style.box-shadow`)

Also you need to remember that function returns a collection, not a single element, so you need to reference it using [0]

> Note that I would recommend not using the raw js approach in this
>   case, I'd prefer to use jQuery as it's much cleaner and once you go beyond anything simple like your code you will be glad you used it

Comment: Simpler to write `topbox[0].className = "welcomebox welcomeBoxMouseOver";`

Comment: I'm actually having a hard time understanding "classname" from the reference manual. So is setAttribute("class","welcomebox welcomeBoxMouseOver") just making it so that welcomebox gains the welcomeBoxMouseOver class?

Comment: @macsplean - yes, that's what is happening. `.className` is a more native way of achieving `setAttribute("class","...")`, they both have the same effect although the accepted wisdom is to use `.className` as it avoids some compatibility issues (`setAttribute` has some issues in some IE versions) and it's faster for lots of elements.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you'll want to do is discover your browser's Dev Tools. On Chrome and IE, press F12, but you can find it somewhere in the menus. The dev tools console reports errors, amongst other things.

Here it would be telling you that `getElementsByClass` doesn't exist on `document`. The method is called `getElementsByClassName` (note the "Name") at the end.

Once past that, you'd find that it would complain that `NodeList` doesn't have a `style` property. `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList` (a list of nodes, in this case elements). Each of those has a `style`, but not the list. So you'd have to loop through the list to work with the style of each element.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't use your event listeners, but gives you an idea of how to apply the drop shadow.  This uses jQuery.
http://jsfiddle.net/KfwyL/20/

I modified your html since it doesn't want you to use head/body tags.

```
<div class="welcomebox"> 
    <h1 class="welcometext" onmouseover="$('.welcomebox').addClass('boxshadow');" onmouseout="$('.welcomebox').removeClass('boxshadow');">Welcome to my site.
    </h1> 
    </div>
```

css:

```
.welcomebox {background-color:#1C0245;
  -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
  -moz-border-radius: 18px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  width: 390px;
  height: 78px;
    margin-left:100px;
    margin-top:28px;
    border-style:solid;
  border-width:medium;
}

h1 {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left: 12px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 357px;
    background-color: #670715;
    padding: 4px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
  -moz-border-radius: 14px;
  border-radius: 14px;
}

h1:hover {background-color: green;}

.boxshadow
{
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working version with a box shadow working correctly without using jQuery:

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KfwyL/31/)

Javascript:

```
welcomeboxshadow = document.getElementById("welcomeH1");
welcomeboxshadow.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {var topbox = document.getElementById("welcomeDiv");
topbox.className = "welcomebox shadowed";
}, false)
welcomeboxshadow.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {var topbox = document.getElementById("welcomeDiv");
topbox.className = "welcomebox";
}, false)
```

HTML changes:

```
  <div class="welcomebox" id="welcomeDiv"> 
    <h1 class="welcometext" id="welcomeH1">Welcome to my site.</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not an expert either, but why not just add:
.welcomebox:hover { box-shadow here }
to your css?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to make it so that if I hover over the h1, the div gets box shadow.